# Frequency of the Primary Circuit in a Spark Gap Tesla Coil

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-circuits, oscillators

In a simple spark gap tesla coil, how does the oscillating current in the primary circuit interact with the supply voltage/current? If the power supply comes from a transformer hooked up to the ac mains for example, with a 60 hz frequency, how does this 60 hz frequency interact with the much higher frequency in the primary circuit?